# Cakephp displaying the latest 4 results in ascending order

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I am trying to display the latest 4 results in ascending order.Please help me in achieving this.

Example:

result3
result4
result5
result6

When i try the following code i getting the following result, but i want the last 4 results in ascending order.

```
$results=$this->Comment->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('feed_id'=>
$feedid,'status'=>'A'),
'recursive' => 1,'order' => 'Comment.id ASC','limit'=>4, 'offset'=>0));
```

result1
result2
result3
result4

Following query will work, but i want to write a cakephp find

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *
FROM `comments` WHERE `feed_id`=46 ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0 , 4) t
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If i good understood your question, here is a solution.

#### mysql

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `comments` AS c
WHERE 
    c.feed_id = 46
ORDER BY 
    c.created DESC, 
    c.id ASC 
LIMIT 4
```

#### cakephp

```
$conditions = array(
    'feed_id'=>46,
    'status'=>'A'
);
$order = array(
    'Comment.created DESC,
    'Comment.id ASC
);
$limit = 4;
$recursive = 1;

# fetch results
$results = $this->Comment->find('all', 
   array(
       'conditions' => $conditions, 
       'recursive' => $recursive, 
       'order' => $order, 
       'limit' => $limit
   )
);
```

Comment: This gives the result result6
result5
result4
result3 but in need result3
result4
result5
result6

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay. Can i please get a structure of the table?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this may not be a "pure" solution, but if the number of rows that you need to display is, as it seems, known and limited, I suggest doing the following:

```
// fetch results
$results = $this->Comment->find('all', 
   array(
       'conditions' => array(
            'feed_id'=>46,
            'status'=>'A'
       ), 
       'recursive' => 1,
       'order' => array(
            'Comment.created DESC',
            'Comment.id DESC'
        ),
       'limit' => 4
   )
);
// Sort them as you need
$results = Hash::sort($results, '{n}.Comment.created', 'asc');
```

The sort can be done either in the Model, the Controller or the View, but I suggest the latter because yours seems more a display requirement than something I would put in the Model.
I have not enough MVC "purity" in me to say for sure.